# Ajax request is canceling other JS events on page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I have a table that is populated with results of an AJAX `onchange` request. Everything works perfectly, but I also have an included JS script that is loaded on window.load which changes the table based on `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `onclick`, etc. However, since the table is not populated until the AJAX request the table JS features do not work. Is there way to populate the table with the AJAX request and instead of doing window.load, load the JS script during or after the AJAX request is complete? Below is my code:

```
<link href="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>/css/table_design.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    
// This is the script that is included, and inside the script
//the main function is started by window.load
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>/js/table_design.js"></script>
    
<br />
                
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(str) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()   {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)   {
                document.getElementById("tars").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","jqueryDB/catSelector?cat="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<span id="tars"></span>
```

Here is my PHP page requested through AJAX:

```
public function catSelector()
{
    $catID = $_GET['cat'];  
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM upload WHERE category = '.$catID);
    $num_rows = $query->num_rows();
    $val = $query->result_array();   
            
    echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
        <th width="50%">File Name:</th>
        <th width="30%">File Size:</th>
        <th>Download Link:</th>
    </tr>';
        
    $c = true;
    foreach($val as $files){
        
         if ($files['size'] >= 1000000000) {
             $files['size'] = round( ($files['size'] / 1000000000) , 2).' GB';
        }
        
        if ($files['size'] >= 1000000) {
            $files['size'] = round( ($files['size'] / 1000000) , 2).' MB';
        }else{
            $files['size'] = round( ($files['size'] / 1000) , 2).' KB';
        }
                
        echo '<tr'.(($c = !$c)?' class="odd"':'').">
            <td>$files[name]</td>
            <td>$files[size]</td>
            <td><a href='$files[location]' >Download</a></td>
        </tr>";
    }
        
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used `XMLHttpRequest` but after reading I think you can do it like this:

```
function showUser(str)  {
    ...
    xmlhttp.open("GET","jqueryDB/catSelector?cat=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.onload = function() { //add click events to table elements (same function you calling now with `window.load` };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please send the js script which you are executing on window load?
Also try to call the script as shown below:-

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
                      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        document.getElementById("tars").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
// call the js script here example test();
```